# Record voice message - javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, voice-recognition

I want to create a chat app where you can record a voice message, and convert the audio to text.

I tried once to make the app (not this app) listen until a word being detected - but after a while of silence it just stops recording,

So how do we make a voice message?
And how can I make the app listen all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try to use the npm package to convert the speech to text

https://github.com/aditya-tripathy/react-native-speech-to-text-android#readme

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to record audio in JS is the [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API).